# Date Formatting in Time Series Codes

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I have a .csv file that looks like this:

| Date | Time | Demand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-05 | 6:30 | 6 |
| 01-Jan-05 | 6:45 | 3 |
| ... |  |  |
| 23-Jan-05 | 21:45 | 0 |
| 23-Jan-05 | 22:00 | 1 |

The days are broken into 15 minute increments from 6:30 - 22:00.

Now, I am trying to do a time series on this, but I am a little lost on the notation of this.

I have the following so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(zoo)

tp <- read.csv(".csv")
tp.ts <- ts(tp$DEMAND, start = c(), end = c(), frequency = 63)
```

The frequency I am after is an entire day, which I believe makes the number 63.***

However, I am unsure as to how to notate the dates in c().

***Edit

If the frequency is meant to be observations per a unit of time, and I am trying to observe just (Demand)  by the 15 minute time slots (Time) in each day (Date), maybe my Frequency is 1?

***Edit 2

So I think I am struggling with doing the time series because I have a Date column (which is characters) and a Time column.

Since I need the data for Demand at the given hours on the dates, maybe I need to convert the dates to be used in ts() and combine the Date and Time date into a new column?

If I do this, I am assuming this should give me the times I need (6:30 to 22:00) but with the addition of having the date?

However, the data is to be used to predict the Demand for the rest of the month. So maybe the Date is an important variable if the day of the week impacts Demand?

Answer (score 0):

We assume you are starting with tp shown reproducibly in the Note at the end. A complete cycle of 24 * 4 = 96 points should be represented by one unit of time internally.  The chron class does that so read it in as a zoo series `z` with chron time index and then convert that to ts giving `ts_ser` or possibly leave it as a zoo series depending on what you are going to do next.

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

to_chron <- function(date, time) as.chron(paste(date, time), "%d-%b-%y %H:%M")
z <- read.zoo(tp, index = 1:2, FUN = to_chron, frequency = 4 * 24)
ts_ser <- as.ts(z)
```

### Note

```
tp <- structure(list(Date = c("01-Jan-05", "01-Jan-05"), Time = c("6:30", 
"6:45"), Demand = c(6L, 3L)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I got chron, however, when I insert your code, I only get two rows returning the dates: (Date = c("01-Jan-05", "01-Jan-05")

Comment: I added additional information above.

Comment: As per the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page questions are supposed to provide reproducible input using `dput`.  Since that wasn't done I did it for you in the Note at the end.  Since only 2 consecutive rows were shown I used 2 rows in the Nnote so you will only get two rows of output in z and ts_ser.  Note that ts class cannot represent daily dates, only monthly, by quarter or annual but you can represent dates using number of days since 1970-01-01 plus fractional times by  using chron as shown.